# Xamarin backdoor invoke - The registrar found a signature mismatch in the method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I want to invoke a backdoor in Xamarin ui test. For one method I need to pass some arguments but it gets a signature mismatch. I followed the official documentation (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.IApp.Invoke/p/System.String/System.Object[]/) so not really an idea why or where it goes wrong.

This is in my app code (AppDelegate.cs)

```
    [Export("ConfigurationBackdoor:")]
    public void ConfigurationBackdoor(NSString configuration, NSString configurationName)
            {
   BackdoorHelper.ConfigurationEventBackdoor(configuration, configurationName);
            }
```

And this is in my code of the xamarin ui tests:

```
object[] arguments = { "arg1", "arg2" };
AppContext.App.Invoke("ConfigurationBackdoor:", arguments);
```

Does someone has a clue why this is not working? On Android it works fine btw.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you can get around this by contacting your Parameters like this:

```
object arguments = "arg1"+" "+"arg2";
AppContext.App.Invoke("ConfigurationBackdoor:", arguments);
```

then you can handle it in your backdoor method like this:

```
[Export("ConfigurationBackdoor:")]
 public void ConfigurationBackdoor(NSString configurations)
 { 
     string cr = (string) configurations;
     string[] confs= cr.Split(' ');
     BackdoorHelper.ConfigurationEventBackdoor(confs[0], confs[1]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Xamarin UI test doesn't allow more then one argument for iOS. On android it was not a problem but on iOS you can only use one argument. Like it is described in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-backdoors).

```
The method must take a parameter of NSString.
```

So I was somewhat creative and put a json string as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Method signature might not be correct (only one parameter). Try "configurationBackdoor:withConfigurationName:". Put this signature on both places (export and invoke).

Comment: Signature is alright but xamarin UI test doesn't allow more then one parameters ...